# vanilla js - classList.add not working, but className does work?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to rewrite/modify a navigation example from the WAI tutorials documentation (https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/menus/flyout/).

My question only concerns the snippet of code below. The original docs use `this.className` which I'm trying to change to `this.classList.add`, but it does nothing at all. There are no errors in the console, and console logging both `navPrimaryLi` and the `mouseover` event works fine.

Why can I not use `this.classList.add`?

```
let navPrimaryLi = document.querySelectorAll('#primary-nav li.menu-item-has-children');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(navPrimaryLi, function(el, i){
  el.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event){
    this.classList.add = 'open'; // does nothing
    // this.className = 'open'; // changes the class name to 'open'
  });
});
```

Many thanks!

Comment: `classList.add()` is a method, not a property! Use it like: `classList.add("open")`.

Comment: You can read more about [`DOMTokenList.add()` here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/add)

Answer (score 2):

Try running add instead assign

```
this.classList.add('open')
```